# Shared element transition - transform color

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Is it possible to animate a `TextView` via a shared element transition and additionally transfrom the color while animating?

I'm transitioning from a text in the activity to a toolbar's text and therefore want to switch the color while transitioning...